# Методы wait и notify

Tags: java, многопоточность, синхронизация

В интернете нашел пример использования `wait` и `notify`:

```
public class ThreadsApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Store store = new Store();
        Producer producer = new Producer(store);
        Consumer consumer = new Consumer(store);
        new Thread(producer).start();
        new Thread(consumer).start();
    }
}

// Класс Магазин, хранящий произведенные товары
class Store {
    private int product = 0;
    private boolean available = false;

    public synchronized void get() {
        while (product < 1) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
        product--;
        System.out.println("Покупатель купил 1 товар");
        System.out.println("Товаров на складе: " + product);
        notify();
    }

    public synchronized void put() {
        while (product >= 3) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
        product++;
        System.out.println("Производитель добавил 1 товар");
        System.out.println("Товаров на складе: " + product);
        notify();
    }
}

// класс Производитель
class Producer implements Runnable {

    Store store;

    Producer(Store store) {
        this.store = store;
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
            store.put();
        }
    }
}

// Класс Потребитель
class Consumer implements Runnable {

    Store store;

    Consumer(Store store) {
        this.store = store;
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
            store.get();
        }
    }
}
```

Вопрос:

1. В реализации методов `get` и `put` есть метод `notify`, который будит потоки, спящие на мониторе `store`, и это происходит каждый раз при их вызове, т.е. когда поток покупатель купил  товар и вызвал `notify` в методе `get`, поток производитель на этом же мониторе УЖЕ ПРОСНУЛСЯ И ЖДЕТ ОСВОБОЖДЕНИЯ МОНИТОРА?
2. Так как вызывается несколько раз `notify`, потому что вызывается несколько раз `get` и `put`, столько же раз происходит пробуждение потоков на мониторе, получается поток уже проснулся, и его еще 2 раза будят - как это с точки зрения правильности?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. `notify` - будит только 1 поток и не известно какой именно.
2. Если никто не ждет, то `notify` ничего не делает.

Попробую пояснить подробно.

1. Поток А захватывает lock и входит в синхронизированный код.
2. Поток А вызывает `wait`, засыпает и освобождает lock.
3. Поток Б захватывает lock и входит в синхронизированный код.
4. Поток Б вызывает `notify`. Возможно (так как не известно какой поток будет разбужен) поток А просыпается становится в очередь на захват lock.
5. Поток Б освобождает lock и выходит из синхронизированного кода.
6. Поток А захватывает lock и продолжает со следующего после `wait` выражения.

Comment: 1) будит первый поток, первый поток просыпается и ждет освобождения монитора?

Comment: я обновил ответ