# Методы wait и notify + syncronized метод

Tags: java, многопоточность, синхронизация

У меня возник вопрос при рассмотрении кода из [связанного вопроса про методы wait и notify](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/611201/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B-wait-%D0%B8-notify)
 (код полностью приведён в этом вопросе, так что дублировать его я не стала). Этот же код был взят из статьи "[Методы wait(), notify() и notifyAll()](http://begoml.by/wait-notify-%D0%B8-notifyall)", и вывод при запуске программе, как описано в этой статье, должен быть следующим:

```
Производитель добавил 1 товар
Товаров на складе: 1
Производитель добавил 1 товар
Товаров на складе: 2
Производитель добавил 1 товар
Товаров на складе: 3
Покупатель купил 1 товар
Товаров на складе: 2
Покупатель купил 1 товар
Товаров на складе: 1
Покупатель купил 1 товар
Товаров на складе: 0
Производитель добавил 1 товар
Товаров на складе: 1
Производитель добавил 1 товар
Товаров на складе: 2
Покупатель купил 1 товар
Товаров на складе: 1
Покупатель купил 1 товар
Товаров на складе: 0
```

Да и на практике, при запуске программы, я вижу такой вывод. Однако я не могу понять, почему при данном алгоритме получается такой результат.

Процитирую описание алгоритма из [ответа на приведённый выше вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/611216/189882):

1. Поток А захватывает lock и входит в синхронизированный код.
2. Поток А вызывает wait, засыпает и освобождает lock.
3. Поток Б захватывает lock и входит в синхронизированный код.
4. Поток Б вызывает notify. Возможно (так как не известно какой поток будет разбужен) поток А просыпается становится в очередь на захват lock.
5. Поток Б освобождает lock и выходит из синхронизированного кода.
6. Поток А захватывает lock и продолжает со следующего после wait выражения.

Почему тогда, после того как "производитель добавил первый товар", или, иначе говоря, после того, как был вызван один раз метод `put`, метод `get` не вызывается сразу, а только после того, как в методе `put` будет вызван метод  `wait`?.. Ведь получается, что поток `Producer` с помощью `syncronized`  входит в синхронизированный код - захватывает монитор объекта `Store`. Метод `wait` на этом этапе не вызывается (так как `product` == 0),  `product` инкрементируется и вызывается метод `notify()`. И поток `Producer` выходит из синхронизированного кода - освобождает монитор объекта `Store`. Получается, что сейчас вполне мог бы выполниться метод `get` потока  `Consumer`  - он должен был быть разбужен методом `notify()` и `product` уже равен 1. Однако продолжает выполняться поток `Producer`, пока у него не вызовется метод `wait`. Почему, что неверно в моих рассуждениях?

Comment: 1. стандартная синхронизация не справедлива, поэтому нет гарантии, что после освобождения монитора пойдет именно consumer, даже если он уже на мониторе ждет. 2. поскольку producer запускается первым, он может успеть наработать еще до запуска consumer. 3. ожидающий поток "засыпает", будить его "долго", поэтому уже активный producer успевает проскочить. Ну и однократные запуски - не показатель, посчитайте несколько тысяч вызовов, вы там увидите разные сценарии с разной частотой.

Answer (score 1):

По моему как-то так

> Почему тогда, после того как "производитель добавил первый товар",
>   или, иначе говоря, после того, как был вызван один раз метод put,
>   метод get не вызывается сразу, а только после того, как в методе put
>   будет вызван метод  wait?

Если метод, объявленный как synchronized, является методом экземпляра, он блокирует монитор, связанный с экземпляром, для которого он вызывается.

Это значит, что метод get не может быть вызван в виду блокировки монитора всего экземпляра. Метод put набирает `product >= 3` и вызывает wait.

> [Если никто не ждет, то notify ничего не делает.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/611216/190461)

Метод get дождавшись освобождения потока также блокирует монитор всего экземпляра пока не станет true `product < 1`. Уступает монитор.

Теперь в очереди попеременно происходит уступка монитора, потому что при вызове метода notify() всегда есть ожидающий поток.

upd

> Так ведь после завершения работы метода put должен же освободиться
>   монитор, связанный с экземпляром?

Producer выполняет put пока `for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)`. В каждой итерации в методе put происходит сверка `product >= 3` и только тогда монитор экземпляра освобождается через wait. Consumer захватывает монитор.

Comment: "Если метод, объявленный как synchronized, является методом экземпляра, он блокирует монитор, связанный с экземпляром, для которого он вызывается. Это значит, что метод get не может быть вызван в виду блокировки монитора всего экземпляра". Так ведь после завершения работы метода `put` должен же освободиться монитор, связанный с экземпляром?..

Comment: А по выходу из syncronized метода разве также не должен освободиться монитора экземпляра? Ведь этот монитор экземпляра, насколько я понимаю, захватывавается при входе в syncronized-метод и освобождается по выходе из него.

Comment: @Ksenia: Вы правы, но, думается мне, ответ кроется в скорости выполнения цикла for. К тому времени как  Consumer встанет в очередь Producer успевает набрать `product >= 3`

Answer (score 0):

В рассуждениях все верно, кроме того факта, что переключения между контекстами относительно ресурсоемки и JVM как мне думается пытается минимизировать их. Эффект блочного выполнения наблюдается даже при добавлении `Thread.yield()` (наивная попытка передать управление другому потоку) и `notifyAll` (вообще ничем не отличается от notify в данном случае):

```
public class ThreadsApp
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Store store = new Store();
        Producer producer = new Producer(store);
        Consumer consumer = new Consumer(store);
        new Thread(producer).start();
        new Thread(consumer).start();
    }
}

// Класс Магазин, хранящий произведенные товары
class Store
{
    private int product = 0;

    public synchronized void get()
    {
        while(product < 1)
        {
            try
            {
                System.out.println("Покупатель wait");
                wait();
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e)
            {
            }
        }
        product--;
        System.out.println("Покупатель купил 1 товар");
        System.out.println("Товаров на складе: " + product);
        notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized void put()
    {
        while(product >= 3)
        {
            try
            {
                System.out.println("Производитель wait");
                wait();
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e)
            {
            }
        }
        product++;
        System.out.println("Производитель добавил 1 товар");
        System.out.println("Товаров на складе: " + product);
        notifyAll();
    }
}

class Producer implements Runnable
{
    Store store;

    Producer(Store store)
    {
        this.store = store;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("Производитель run");
        for(int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
        {
            store.put();
            Thread.yield();
        }
    }
}

class Consumer implements Runnable
{
    Store store;

    Consumer(Store store)
    {
        this.store = store;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("Покупатель run");
        for(int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
        {
            store.get();
            Thread.yield();
        }
    }
}
```

получаем:

```
Покупатель run
Производитель run
Покупатель wait
Производитель добавил 1 товар
Товаров на складе: 1
Покупатель купил 1 товар
Товаров на складе: 0
Производитель добавил 1 товар
Товаров на складе: 1
Производитель добавил 1 товар
Товаров на складе: 2
Производитель добавил 1 товар
Товаров на складе: 3
Покупатель купил 1 товар
Товаров на складе: 2
Покупатель купил 1 товар
Товаров на складе: 1
Покупатель купил 1 товар
Товаров на складе: 0
Производитель добавил 1 товар
Товаров на складе: 1
Покупатель купил 1 товар
Товаров на складе: 0
```